# Unable to convert original date using dateFromString

Tags: objective-c, date, nsstring, converters, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a time string using the following code

```
NSString *origDate = @"2012-12-06T09:27:18+08:00";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss VVVV"];
NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:origDate];
```

However when I print the convertedDate, it returns me null. My guess is that the Date format U am using does not match. How can I modify the code to make it work? What format can I use to match my string?

EDIT (After referring to apple's documentation)

I checked the date format documentation on apple's page and found the following code

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];
```

The format above seems to match what I have in the original date string "2012-12-06T09:27:18+08:00". However I am still getting a null value back. Am I getting closer? How else can I update this?

Comment: Your guess is correct. The source date string looks thoroughly bunged; do you have any control over that? Seems as though there should be a space between the date and the time and the time zone. But beside that, yes, you do have to make changes to the string you've specified for the date formatter.

Comment: @trudyscousin It's created by my system, but I am sure I can manipulate the original string. But you are saying that there are no 'setDateFormat' I can use to convert my current string?

Comment: No, not at all. [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) in Apple's documentation will steer you to the documentation you need to fashion the string correctly. Look in the section "Fixed Formats".

Comment: @trudyscousin I checked out the doc as you suggested and found something that seems to check for a similar format, however it's still returning me a null value. Do you mind helping me take a look again at my original post?

Comment: In iOS 5 you can't read a timestamp with ":" in the timezone offset -- you have to remove that character somehow.  In iOS 6 you can, but only with "ZZZZZ".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original input, this format string provided to your date formatter should get the job done:

```
@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ"
```

Note: I had tested this under Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

The format String will parse on iOS6 (not iOS5 -> nil) but it is useless for output, since the parsed date will loose it's timezone information.
Output will be something like "2012-12-06T17:27:18Z" in iOS6 maybe this is depending on wether the timezone is set to GMT.

my Code:

```
    static NSDateFormatter    *gXmlDateFormatter = nil;
// lazy init
+ (NSDateFormatter *)xmlDateFormatter
{
    // e.g. updateDateTime="2012-09-18T11:06:19+00:00"
    if (gXmlDateFormatter == nil) {
        // prepare for parsinf Arinc-ISO-XML-dates input
        gXmlDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        gXmlDateFormatter = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        gXmlDateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

        gXmlDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ";    // only parsing! in iOS 6 (iOS5 will parse nil)
//        gXmlDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ";        // all iOS but with NO colons in timeZone (add/remove)
    }
    NSLog(@"gXmlDateFormatter:%@",gXmlDateFormatter);
    return gXmlDateFormatter;
}
// there's a problem with the above dateformater and iOS5 creating nil-results
+ (NSDate *)dateFromXMLString:(NSString *)arincDateString
{
    NSString *dateString = arincDateString;

    // xmlDateStrings may contain a ':' in the timezone part. iOS and Unicode DO NOT
    // so always remove the xml-standard colon ':' from the timezone to make it iOS/Unicode compatible
    // xml: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp
    // iOS: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)
    NSRange zRange = NSMakeRange(arincDateString.length-3, 1);
    dateString = [arincDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:zRange];

    NSDate *date = [self.arincDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    if(!date)NSLog(@"PARSING arincDateString:'%@' -> (NSDate*)%@ ",arincDateString,date);

    return date;
}
+ (NSString *)xmlStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    if( !date ) return nil;        // exit on nil date

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *dateString = [self.arincDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

        // iOS5 does not use a ':' in the timeZone part but xml needs it
        // so allways add the xml-standard colon ':' into the timezone
        NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:dateString];
        if( 22 < string.length ) {        // prevent crashing
            [string insertString:@":" atIndex:22];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"date output string too short:%d<22",string.length);
        }
        dateString = string;

        if(!dateString)
            NSLog(@"OUTPUT '%@' -> (NSString*)%@",date,dateString);
        return dateString;
    }
}
```